# How do you enable windowed full-screen mode?

Tags: league-of-legends

Windowed full-screen is preferable because it allows quick alt-tabbing without hiding the game display (which is nice with two monitors). How is the setting enabled?

Comment: windowed full screen? do you mean -noborder?

Comment: @Simon I'm not sure what you mean by -noborder. I would try passing it as an argument to the client, but there is a separate launcher for it.

Comment: Steam has it, and if you launch a game through steam you can use -noborder and then -w and -h to specify height and width

Comment: @SimonSheehan That only applies to games that use the Source engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I never played LoL, but, according to a quick google search, there are two ways:

1. Run the game in windowed mode, set the resolution so that it matches exactly your desktop resolution, then hide the window borders using [ShiftWindow](http://www.grismar.net/shiftwindow/).
2. Put `BorderlessWindow=1` in your `Config\gam‌​e.cfg` and you should have no need for ShiftWindow. ([source](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=601711))

Again, I never played League of Legends, I just googled this information and have no idea if any of this will work.

Comment: I do play LoL, and can second this answer. In fact, with a duel-monitor setup myself, I just use step 1, but I guess removing the border would give you the extra like ten pixels on top, I suppose.

Comment: ShiftWindow looks interesting, but I prefer using the configuration method. The path you listed does not seem correct, but making the change to this file seems to work:
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.0.60\deploy\DATA\CFG\game.cfg
Hopefully the location doesn't change when the version number changes. If you update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: No longer valid. See answer by Angel Neev. New location:
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\game.cfg set windowed = 1, borderlesswindow = 1

Answer (score 2):

The new location is C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config.
Search there for the game.cfg file and change:

- Windowed from 0 to 1
- BorderlessWindow from 0 to 1

Comment: Verified current and working Dec. 9, 2012.